# Redundant HLS Streams in Wowza

Tags: java, http-live-streaming, wowza

Is it possible to add alternate (backup) streams to an HLS manifests in Wowza when using the Java API to generate the dynamic playlist (AMLST).

I have a code like this where I add dynamically the different bitrates, but I would like to add one backup stream. (I tried adding a second MediaListSegment but it does not seem to work).

```
package com.wowza.wms.plugin.test.module;

import com.wowza.wms.medialist.*;
import com.wowza.wms.module.*;
import com.wowza.wms.stream.*;
import com.wowza.wms.application.*;

public class ModuleAMLSTTestLive extends ModuleBase 
{
class MyMediaListProvider implements IMediaListProvider
{
    public MediaList resolveMediaList(IMediaListReader mediaListReader, IMediaStream stream, String streamName)
    {
        MediaList mediaList = new MediaList();

        MediaListSegment segment = new MediaListSegment();
        mediaList.addSegment(segment);

        MediaListRendition rendition1 = new MediaListRendition();
        segment.addRendition(rendition1);

        rendition1.setName(streamName+"_400");
        rendition1.setBitrateAudio(128000);
        rendition1.setBitrateVideo(400000);
        rendition1.setWidth(320);
        rendition1.setHeight(240);
        rendition1.setAudioCodecId("mp4a.40.2");
        rendition1.setVideoCodecId("avc1.66.12");

        MediaListRendition rendition2 = new MediaListRendition();
        segment.addRendition(rendition2);

        rendition2.setName(streamName+"_800");
        rendition2.setBitrateAudio(128000);
        rendition2.setBitrateVideo(800000);
        rendition2.setWidth(640);
        rendition2.setHeight(480);
        rendition2.setAudioCodecId("mp4a.40.2");
        rendition2.setVideoCodecId("avc1.77.31");

        return mediaList;
    }
}

public void onAppStart(IApplicationInstance appInstance)
{
    appInstance.setMediaListProvider(new MyMediaListProvider());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this is not supported in the API, I finally found a solution:

**It is possible to define main and backup streams by specifing the streams with the absolute path of the stream in the URI or DOMAIN cupertino tags.**

Sample smil:

```
<body>
  <switch>
      <video src="mp4:foo.mp4" system-bitrate="300000">
    <param name="videoCodecId" value="avc1.66.30" valuetype="data"/>
    <param name="audioCodecId" value="mp4a.40.2" valuetype="data"/>
    <param name="cupertinoTag.URI" value="http://serverwowza1.foo.com:1935/vod/mp4:foo.mp4/chunklist.m3u8" valuetype="data"/>
      </video>
      <video src="mp4:foo.mp4" system-bitrate="300000" >
    <param name="videoCodecId" value="avc1.66.30" valuetype="data"/>
    <param name="audioCodecId" value="mp4a.40.2" valuetype="data"/>
    <param name="cupertinoTag.URI" value="http://serverwowza2.foo.com:1935/vod/mp4:sample.mp4/chunklist.m3u8" valuetype="data"/>
      </video>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution has one significant problem, your chunklist URIs do not include a ***Wowza session id*** (the "_w#####" bit normally in the chunklist filename), which it really couldn't because you can't possibly know what that is at the time you create the smil file.  Without the ***session id*** then every request for that chunklist from every player will create a new "Wowza HTTP session", which could cause a number of issues over time, like Java heap consumption and the inability to track the actual number of clients connected.

The better (albeit undocumented) solution is to replace your two entries with a single entry that specifies a "cupertinoTag.DOMAIN" param with your two domains:

```
  <video src="mp4:foo.mp4" system-bitrate="300000">
<param name="videoCodecId" value="avc1.66.30" valuetype="data"/>
<param name="audioCodecId" value="mp4a.40.2" valuetype="data"/>
<param name="cupertinoTag.DOMAIN" value="serverwowza1.foo.com:1935,serverwowza2.foo.com:1935" valuetype="data"/>
  </video>
```

It should then create two fully-formed absolute chunklist entries (EXT-X-STREAM-INF tags followed by their associated URI) in the resulting master playlist, one for each domain, including the ***session id***.

Note that a session with the specified ***id*** would be created upon the initial request for the chunklist (from the same player) on the backup server.

---

For amlst API you can actually do this same thing through the rendition ***properties*** member.

```
        rendition.getProperties().setProperty("cupertinoTag.DOMAIN", "serverwowza1.foo.com:1935,serverwowza2.foo.com:1935");
```